# Nested DIV in a responsive design - margin, padding, etc

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It's been a while since I really dealt with percentages in web design. I have a nested DIV which sits inside a container but the padding of the container pushes it beyond the 100% width. Without wishing to embark on a process of trial and error to see what makes it as close to 100% of the width as possible, how do I go about achieving a snug fit? I also noticed that when I resized the window and made the space smaller, the right hand padding simply got smaller.

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="inside">ssdfsdfdfsfdf</div>
</div>

#block {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 20px;
}
.inside {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/cs2U9/4/

Comment: you could make the padding also a percentage value and then padding + width = 100%

Comment: Why don't the JSFiddle code and the code you posted match? This uses padding, while your example uses margins..? The version with the margins looks pretty tight to me. You might want to give `.inner` an overflow value, but aside from that, not seeing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong Fiddle. It's fixed... http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/cs2U9/4/

Comment: Why not just give the .inside div a margin of 20px and skip the padding altogether?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it... I need overflow: hidden on the container DIV. My stupidity... :) Thanks

Comment: Updated and working... http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/cs2U9/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `box-sizing` css property for #block element.

```
#block {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 20px;

    -o-box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera */
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Mozilla */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, Safari */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

About CSS box-sizing property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: It's kind of surprising however that this can't be achieved without using CSS that isn't yet CSS3 validated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an

```
overflow: hidden
```

on the container DIV in order to get it to sit perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/cs2U9/6/